# Weird chrome storage bug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, storage, content-script

I have a weird problem, I noticed that the content script only retrieves values using `chrome.storage.local.get` when I use an `alert` to show them (they have to be called somehow first for them to show) any help on this will be appreciated.

```
var ref;
var max;
var min;
var disc;

chrome.storage.local.get([
      'ref',
      'max',
      'min',
      'disc'
   ], function(data){
       ref    = parseFloat(data.ref);

       max    = parseFloat(data.max);

       min    = parseFloat(data.min);

       disc   = parseFloat(data.disc); 

       console.log('Values Gotten');
});  

function main() {
    setTimeout(function(){refresh()},ref*1000);
}

function refresh(){ 
    window.location = "-----some webpage------[its filled in actual code]"; 
}
```

Comment: Show us your problematic code.

Comment: added to the main post

Comment: Where did you call `alert`?

Comment: in the main functions start ( main function is called to by an if right after chrome storage get)

Comment: I suspect `main` gets called before the `chrome.storage.local` callback. You need to call `main` inside the callback.

Comment: i see, however calling main in the callback might be a bit too complicated as the structure that calls main function is an  - IF- with a lot of ELSE IFs, i will try that though, thank you

Comment: Seems like that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.storage.local.get` call is asynchronous, which means that the function returns immediately and the callback gets called later.

If you call `main` after `chrome.storage.local.get`, `ref` will still be undefined, because callback, that assigns this variable, still wasn't executed.

To prevent that you need to call `main` when the `ref` variable gets assigned.
To do that you need to call `main` inside the callback.

```
var ref;
var max;
var min;
var disc;

chrome.storage.local.get([
        'ref',
        'max',
        'min',
        'disc'
    ], function(data) {
        ref    = parseFloat(data.ref);
        max    = parseFloat(data.max);
        min    = parseFloat(data.min);
        disc   = parseFloat(data.disc);

        console.log('Values Gotten');

        main();
});  

function main() {
    setTimeout(function(){refresh()},ref*1000);
}

function refresh() { 
    window.location = "-----some webpage------[its filled in actual code]"; 
}
```